# Regex on MediaWiki links

Tags: regex, mediawiki

I need help trying to fix a regex to use on a MediaWiki site, particularly in the field of links.

What I want to accomplish is turning `[[<name> (<identifier>)|<name>]]` to just `{{<template>|<link>|<identifier>}}` but the regex I made seems to be screwing around with how it works.

Take these two strings for instance:

```
====[[<link #1>]] [[<link #2 name> (<link #2 identifier>)|<link #2 name>]]====
[[<link #3 name> (<link #3 identifier>)|<link #3 name>]]
```

My regex is `/\[\[(.*?) \((.*?)\)\|(.*?)]]/gm`
Under circumstances, the result should have just caught `[[<link #2 name> (<link #2 identifier>)|<link #2 name>]]` and `[[<link #3 name> (<link #3 identifier>)|<link #3 name>]]`

Instead, the regex captures `[[<link #1>]] [[<link #2 name> (<link #2 identifier>)|<link #2 name>]]` and `[[<link #3 name> (<link #3 identifier>)|<link #3 name>]]`, leaving the end result when I replace with `{{<template>|$1|$2}}` as:

```
===={{<template>|<link #1>]] [[<link #2 name>|<link #2 identifier>}}====
{{<template>|<link #3 name>|<link #3 identifier>}}
```

I need help with this. I tried looking around the internet, and I can't find a way to prevent the regex from trying to overlap with other links

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
\[\[((?:(?!\[\[)[^()])*)\s+\(((?:(?!\[\[)[^()])*)\)\|(.*?)]]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EW9ZpE/1). *Details*:

- `\[\[` - a `[[` string
- `((?:(?!\[\[)[^()])*)` - Group 1: zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`  each of which does not start a `[[` substring
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `((?:(?!\[\[)[^()])*)` - Group 2: zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`  each of which does not start a `[[` substring
- `\)\|` - a `)|` string
- `(.*?)` - Group 3: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `]]` - a `]]` string.